# Jenkins: how to run two different Sonar analysis in a Maven build?

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

Hope someone can help.

- We have a Jenkins server
- We have 2 Sonar servers with different configurations
- Our projects use Maven

We need to configure a Maven build in Jenkins that analyzes our project with the 2 Sonar server.

We've configured the two Sonar installations in Jenkins but we can add only one Sonar analysis in the post-build actions.

Is it possible to add multiple Sonar analysis in the post-build actions? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Maybe you could add a post compile command line action for the second Sonar analysis...

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22068919/1005481) for a discussion on how to achieve something like this from within the Maven build.