# one master pom file with multiple profiles and sonar analysis for each profile

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, pom.xml, maven-profiles

My project totally has 50 modules and 10 profiles in it. 
5 profiles are used to build 5 products and 5 profiles to unit-test the same 5 product.

30 Common modules and 4 modules for each profile building each product.
Now i have to see how to integrate the SONAR analysis with Jenkins job for each product.

i need 5 entries to be seen in sonar, one for each product and yet i have a single pom file. Can this be accomplished.

Please help. sample pom file below

```
<modules>
        <!-- Script related projects -->
        <!-- Common modules -->
        <module>./././bundles/com.abc.module1</module>
        <module>./././bundles/com.abc.module2</module>
            .
            .
        <module>./././bundles/com.abc.module30</module>
</modules>

<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>product1</id>
            <modules>
                <module>./././bundles/com.abc.module31</module>
                <module>./././bundles/com.abc.module32</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>product1-tests</id>
            <modules>
                <module>./././bundles/com.abc.testmodule1</module>
                <module>./././bundles/com.abc.testmodule2</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
        .
        .
        .

</profiles>
```

Comment: may be this is what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068919/how-to-configure-maven-to-run-a-sonarqube-project-analysis-with-two-different-qu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sonar builds a project based on 'artifactId' tag. Since for a pom file we have only 1 'artifactId', we can have only 1 project listed in sonarqube. we have to have multiple pom files for multiple sonar project entries.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have one now, I'd just create a profile that includes all source modules and have a single jenkins job that runs sonar to build and analyze that single profile.  Sonar is going to give you quality metrics and coverage for your source so you only need a one sonar project that contains all your source for this.  This profile should include your tests, but only for collecting coverage data as the tests run - you don't need quality measures on your tests (unless you're interested in that sort of thing).

Comment: Hi tdrury,
I already have this pom configs to build and unit-test my 5 projects. My problem is not getting the sonar analysis in sonarqube for all 5. is this achievable?

Comment: Do you want them as 1 project in Sonar or 5?

Comment: i need 5 different projects in sonar

Comment: Then add the sonar post-build action to your job, but make sure you set the branch name in the advanced options and it must be different for each sonar project.  Alternately, you can create 5 new jenkins jobs that run the sonar action and set the branch name for each to a different value.